# Clojure (clara rule) file not generated when gradle build

Tags: java, spring, gradle, clojure

I have a Spring application that integrates a clara rule engine (clojure) file that is triggered from a java class. When building the app with gradle, the clojure file is not generated as part of the JAR.

So, when running ther jar, it throws the following exception:

`Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate au/com/acme/mti/mec/runtime/rules/mec__init.class or au/com/acme/mti/mec/runtime/rules/mec.clj on classpath.`

What is the best way (or at least a way) to make gradle generates the clj file when building/generating the jar?

I have already include a task in the build.gradle file to copy the clj file from src path to the build path. It copies the file under the build path, but it does not in the jar.

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.1.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'jacoco'
}

group = 'au.com.acme.mti.mec'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url "http://clojars.org/repo"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.clojure:clojure:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.cerner:clara-rules:0.20.0'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    
    }
    
}

task copyRules(type: Copy){
    from 'src/main/resources/au.com.acme.mti.mec.runtime.rules/'
    into 'build/classes/java/main/au/com/acme/mti/mec/runtime/rules/'
}

test {
    test.dependsOn copyRules
    useJUnitPlatform()
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination file("${buildDir}/jacocoHtml")
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the .clj files just into `src/main/resources/au/com/acme/mti/mec/runtime/rules` directly?  otherwise it looks also like you are only depending on the `copyRules` task for the tests? and you are talking about building a jar - does it work in your tests?

Comment: Yes, that is what the gradle task does: copying the files form `src/main/resources/au.com.acme.mti.mec.runtime.rules` into `build/classes/java/main/au/com/acme/mti/mec/runtime/rules`

Comment: That does not answer either question: why do you need this copy task? why not just put the files where they end up on the correct place in the first place? And why is the copy task not executed for building the jar?

Comment: I have tried putting the rules file within the resources. When that is done the .clj file gets packaged within resources, but the problem that then arises is that the java program running clara cant find the rules file located within resources.
​
The addition of the copy task was there to try and fix this issue. This obviously doesn't solve the issue which is why I am reaching out on SO

Comment: I have added a project to my answer, that shows a dedicated copy task is not needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the Clojure files (the Clara rules) in a place, where they end up in the correct place inside the JAR, would make the copy task obsolute (which is not used for building the JAR -- at least from the part of the `build.gradle` we can see in the question.

1. Move the files from `src/main/resources/au.com.acme.mti.mec.runtime.rules` to `src/main/resources/au/com/acme/mti/mec/runtime/rules`
2. Get rid of the `copyRules` task (and it's `dependsOn`)

#### edit:

Added a repository that shows a minimal working example, that puts the clj files just into resources https://github.com/christoph-frick/try-java-clara